# What is this military related building in New York City area?

Tags: 20th-century, new-york-state, photo-identification, 1950s, building

I have three photos of what appear to be the same building, taken in consecutive succession on the same roll of film around June 1958.  I see military folks in the photos.  The photos are taken near New York City or Tarrytown, New York.

First one shot is a side view:

[image]

Next is an entryway, showing military walking towards us from inside the court yard:

[image]

Finally, apparently pulled back from building, across the street, showing military getting into a vehicle:

[image]

Perhaps knowing which branch of the military the men are from would help?  Do their uniforms make that clear?

Detail of sidewalk man:

[image]

Detail of entry way:

[image]

Detail of last photo:

[image]

Can anyone identify this building?

---

[Here is what appears to be same building](https://www.voanews.com/usa/accident-involving-20-cadets-west-point-training-site#&gid=1&pid=1) at West Point in 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the West Point Military Academy, the West Academic Building, designed by Richard Morris Hunt and built in 1895; renovated in 1959 and renamed Pershing Barracks

Comment: https://grandlight.com/portfolio/west-point-pershing-barracks/